# Media Recorder error: MediaRecorder: start failed: -380

Tags: android

media recorder works fine but sometime it gives error. testing on different devices but same error occurs. their is no background service running like mic etc...

```
E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38
06-04 14:09:26.977 13458-13458/com.aykuttasil.callrecorder W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:946)
        at com.aykuttasil.callrecord.receiver.CallRecordReceiver.startRecord(CallRecordReceiver.java:105)
        at
```

.....
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
the code is

```
 private void startRecord(Context context, String seed, String phoneNumber) {
        try {
            boolean isSaveFile = PrefsHelper.readPrefBool(context, CallRecord.PREF_SAVE_FILE);
            Log.i(TAG, "isSaveFile: " + isSaveFile);

            // dosya kayıt edilsin mi?
            if (!isSaveFile) {
                return;
            }

            if (isRecordStarted) {
                try {
                    recorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    // RuntimeException is thrown when stop() is called immediately after start().
                    // In this case the output file is not properly constructed ans should be deleted.
                    Log.d(TAG, "RuntimeException: stop() is called immediately after start()");
                    //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                    audiofile.delete();
                }
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                isRecordStarted = false;
            } else {
                if (prepareAudioRecorder(context, seed, phoneNumber)) {

                    recorder.start();
                    isRecordStarted = true;
                    onRecordingStarted(context, callRecord, audiofile);
                    Log.i(TAG, "record start");
                } else {
                    releaseMediaRecorder();
                }
                //new MediaPrepareTask().execute(null, null, null);
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            releaseMediaRecorder();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            releaseMediaRecorder();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            releaseMediaRecorder();
        }
    }

 private boolean prepareAudioRecorder(Context context, String seed, String phoneNumber) {
        try {
            String file_name = PrefsHelper.readPrefString(context, CallRecord.PREF_FILE_NAME);
            String dir_path = PrefsHelper.readPrefString(context, CallRecord.PREF_DIR_PATH);
            String dir_name = PrefsHelper.readPrefString(context, CallRecord.PREF_DIR_NAME);
            boolean show_seed = PrefsHelper.readPrefBool(context, CallRecord.PREF_SHOW_SEED);
            boolean show_phone_number = PrefsHelper.readPrefBool(context, CallRecord.PREF_SHOW_PHONE_NUMBER);
            int output_format = PrefsHelper.readPrefInt(context, CallRecord.PREF_OUTPUT_FORMAT);
            int audio_source = PrefsHelper.readPrefInt(context, CallRecord.PREF_AUDIO_SOURCE);
            int audio_encoder = PrefsHelper.readPrefInt(context, CallRecord.PREF_AUDIO_ENCODER);

            File sampleDir = new File(dir_path /*+ "/" + dir_name*/);

            if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                sampleDir.mkdirs();
            }

            StringBuilder fileNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            fileNameBuilder.append(file_name);
            fileNameBuilder.append("_");

            if (show_seed) {
                fileNameBuilder.append(seed);
                fileNameBuilder.append("_");
            }

            if (show_phone_number) {
                fileNameBuilder.append(phoneNumber);
                fileNameBuilder.append("_");
            }


            file_name = fileNameBuilder.toString();

            String suffix = "";
            switch (output_format) {

                case MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB: {
                    suffix = ".amr";
                    break;
                }

                case MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP: {
                    suffix = ".3gp";
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    suffix = ".amr";
                    break;
                }
            }

            audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, suffix, sampleDir);

            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(audio_source);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(output_format);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(audio_encoder);
            recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
            recorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {

                }
            });

            try {
                recorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post the logcat here